# Problem with copy values from a simple table to a table from structure for a specified address in C Code

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have a problem with this code when I want to copy value from a table to another table in a structure with a specified address of the table in the structure.

I put the code example below. If I use PtrTableStruct, that does not work. If I use PtrTableStruc2, that works but no address is specified. Somebody can help me, please :)

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned short Table_Truc[256];
  unsigned short Table_Essai[256];
} ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char TheTable[2];

    ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE *PtrStruct = (ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE*) 0x1000000;
    unsigned char* PtrTableStruct = (unsigned char*) &PtrStruct->Table_Essai[0];

    unsigned char* PtrTableStruct2 = (unsigned char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(unsigned short));

    printf("address TheTable 0x%x\n",TheTable);
    printf("address PtrStruct 0x%x\n", PtrStruct);
    printf("address PtrTableStruct 0x%x\n", PtrTableStruct);
    printf("address PtrTableStruct2 0x%x\n", PtrTableStruct2);

    TheTable[0] = 100;
    TheTable[1] = 101;

    unsigned char * NewTable = TheTable;

    int iter;

    for(iter=0;iter<2;iter++){
        *PtrTableStruct++ = *NewTable++;  // that does not work
//      *PtrTableStruct2++ = *NewTable++;  // that works
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this code and the one marked as "works" leaks memory.

Comment: Where did you find that `(ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE*) 0x1000000` is a valid address???

Answer (score 0):

This assignment:

```
ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE *PtrStruct = (ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE*) 0x1000000;
```

is probably not going to do what you expect it to.  There is nothing to indicate sufficient memory is allocated at address `0x1000000`, or that that location is owned by your process.

In general, since you have:

```
typedef struct
{
  unsigned short Table_Truc[256];
  unsigned short Table_Essai[256];
} ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE;
```

...then you can get a pointer to an instance of that struct by creating an instance and a pointer:

```
ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE instanceOfTable[2] = {0}, *ptrToInstanceOfTable = NULL;
```

...and assigning the pointer to the address of the instance:

```
ptrToInstanceOfTable  = &instanceOfTable[0];//pointer is pointing 
                                            //to legal memory owned by the process.
```

Now, `ptrToInstanceOfTable` is pointing to an area of memory sufficient for an array of 2 `ESSAI_STRUC_TABLE`.

By the same reasoning, this statement:

```
unsigned char * NewTable = TheTable;
```

Can be written as:

```
unsigned char *NewTable = &TheTable[0];
```